# Conditional cumulative sum in R with NA and keeping track of episodic wave

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(time = 0:9,
  y_ex1 = c(1,NA,0,1,NA,NA,NA,1,0,0),
  y_ex2 = c(1,NA,0,0,NA,NA,NA,1,0,0),
  y_ex3 = c(1,NA,0,1,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0),
  y_ex4 = c(1,NA,0,0,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0),
  y_ex5 = c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0),

)
```

And I'd like to score each of these vectors as follows:

```
df$y_ex1_scored <- c(1, 1.5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0)
df$y_ex2_scored <- c(1, 1.5, 0, 0, .5, 1, 1.5, 2.5, 0, 0)
df$y_ex3_scored <- c(1, 1.5, 0, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 0, 0, 0)
df$y_ex4_scored <- c(1, 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
df$y_ex5_scored <- c(1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0)
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is calculate a cumulative sum until I have a 0 or an NA. If I hit a 0, I want the sum to start all over again at 0. If I hit an NA, I want the score to depend on what the value was before and after the NA. If the values are the same, then I want the cumulative sum to continue. For example, if they are both 1, I want the sum to continue as though the data were not missing. If they are both 0, the NAs should be replaced with 0s. If the values are different, I want to add a .5 where each NA.

I also want to keep track of each wave and a wave occurs when the values shift from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0. So for the `y_ex1` variable, it should look like

```
y_ex1_wave <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
```

and for `y_ex4` it would be

```
y_ex4_wave <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

Happy to clarify this, I have been writing a bunch of terrible loops in R to try to do this and have spent far to0 long and have made little progress. Happy to have a base R or tidyverse solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that'll help:

```r
fun <- function(z) {
  r <- rle(replace(z, is.na(z), Inf))
  for (na in which(is.infinite(r$values))) {
    if (na %in% c(1L, length(r$values))) {
      stop("oops?")
    } else {
      r$values[na] <- ifelse(r$values[na-1] == r$values[na+1], r$values[na-1], 0.5)
    }
  }
  z2 <- inverse.rle(r)
  ave(z2, cumsum(z2 == 0), FUN = cumsum)
}
```

Demonstration:

```r
out <- as.data.frame(lapply(df[,2:6], fun))
names(out) <- paste0(names(out), "_scored")
all.equal(out, df[,7:11])
# [1] TRUE
out
#    y_ex1_scored y_ex2_scored y_ex3_scored y_ex4_scored y_ex5_scored
# 1           1.0          1.0          1.0          1.0            1
# 2           1.5          1.5          1.5          1.5            2
# 3           0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0            0
# 4           1.0          0.0          1.0          0.0            0
# 5           2.0          0.5          1.5          0.0            1
# 6           3.0          1.0          2.0          0.0            2
# 7           4.0          1.5          2.5          0.0            3
# 8           5.0          2.5          0.0          0.0            0
# 9           0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0            0
# 10          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0            0
```

Brief walk-through of the `fun`ction:

- `rle` is for run-length encoding, which converts something like `c(1,1,2,2,2,3)` into `c(1,2,3)` (values) and `c(2,3,1)` (lengths of each value). This is useful here so that we can easily keep track of `NA`s for revaluing.
- Unfortunately, `rle` (and most of R) treats `NA` as "it could be anything", so (from `?rle`) *"Missing values are regarded as unequal to the previous value"*. Because of this, `NA` will not be collapsed (as in rows 5-7); however, as a trick, and assuming you have all finite values, I replace `NA`s with `Inf` so that I can do what needs to be done. Any "sentinel" value would work here (such as `-99`), I though `Inf` was unambiguous. And since we replace all of these values with the preceding value or `0.5` later, we don't care that the intermediate value was `Inf`.
- We need to iterate over each of the *collapsed* (by `rle`) infinite values (formerly `NA`), and look at the preceding and following. **Note**: I explicitly `stop` (error) if the infinite (NA) values are first or last, but for a more robust function, you will likely need to replace `stop("oops")` with some better logic.
- By replacing the *singular* `Inf` with either the preceding value or `0.5`, we can then use `inverse.rle` which (as might guess) converts the pair of values-and-lengths to a single vector, as before. (You might be comforted to know that `inverse.rle(rle(vec))` should be an identical `vec`tor.)
- The call to `ave(..)` does a grouping function: `cumsum(z2 == 0)` helps us break the vector into groups where the first is a `0` (or the whole original vector unbroken, if `0` is never found). On each of these subvectors, we call `cumsum`. For instance, if `vec <- c(1,2,0,3,4)`, then `ave(vec, cumsum(vec==0), FUN=cumsum)` will first call `cumsum(c(1,2))` then call `cumsum(c(0,3,4))`, and the cumulative-sums are placed in the correct places in the returned vector. (The `ave` function also works well with grouping operations that do not assume contiguous groups, but that's for another question.)

From there, we call this function on each column using `lapply`.

---

*Edit*: I don't want to assume what logic you would want to use for first/last value being `NA`, but you might do something like this:

```r
fun <- function(z) {
  r <- rle(replace(z, is.na(z), Inf))
  for (na in which(is.infinite(r$values))) {
    if (na == 1L) {
      r$values[na] <- 0
    } else if (na == length(r$values)) {
      r$values[na] <- r$values[na-1]
    } else {
      r$values[na] <- ifelse(r$values[na-1] == r$values[na+1], r$values[na-1], 0.5)
    }
  }
  z2 <- inverse.rle(r)
  ave(z2, cumsum(z2 == 0), FUN = cumsum)
}
```

Comment: How I can replace `stop("oops")` so that it works when a vector starts or ends with `NA`? For example, if I have a vector `z <- c(NA,1,1,0,0,NA,NA,1,1,NA)` and it should be scored as z.score <- c(NA, 1, 2, 0, 0, .5, 1, 2, 3, NA)` ? I thought I could just replace `stop("oops?")` with `r$values[na] <- NA`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: It's what I said in the answer: you need to use better logic, notably logic you did not include in your question. Reasonable mechanisms: if it starts with `NA`, use one of `0`, `0.5`, or the next value; if it ends with `NA`, carry the last non-`NA` value forward. My answer implements exactly the problem as you stated it, I did not embellish, which is why I added the text as I did.

Comment: See my edit @cdd, and if it does not give you the intended _mechanism_ for how to approach the problem, please edit your question and be explicit about the corner cases.

Comment: Yes, this does now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
fn <- function(x){
  x <- zoo::na.approx(x)
  x[x>0&x<1] <- 0.5
  grp <- data.table::rleid(!x)
  data.frame(wave = grp, scored = ave(x, grp, FUN = cumsum))
}

cbind(df1, lapply(df1[-1], fn))

   y_ex1.wave y_ex1.scored y_ex2.wave y_ex2.scored y_ex3.wave y_ex3.scored y_ex4.wave y_ex4.scored y_ex5.wave y_ex5.scored
1           1          1.0          1          1.0          1          1.0          1          1.0          1            1
2           1          1.5          1          1.5          1          1.5          1          1.5          1            2
3           2          0.0          2          0.0          2          0.0          2          0.0          2            0
4           3          1.0          2          0.0          3          1.0          2          0.0          2            0
5           3          2.0          3          0.5          3          1.5          2          0.0          3            1
6           3          3.0          3          1.0          3          2.0          2          0.0          3            2
7           3          4.0          3          1.5          3          2.5          2          0.0          3            3
8           3          5.0          3          2.5          4          0.0          2          0.0          4            0
9           4          0.0          4          0.0          4          0.0          2          0.0          4            0
10          4          0.0          4          0.0          4          0.0          2          0.0          4            0
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could do:

```
fn <- function(x){
  y <- cummax(seq_along(x)*!is.na(x))
  idx <-which(is.na(x))
  x[idx] <- (x[y[idx]] + x[rank(y,ties.method = 'max')[idx]+1])/2
  grp <- cumsum(!x)
  data.frame(score = ave(x,grp , FUN = cumsum), wave = grp)
}
 cbind(df1, lapply(df1[-1], fn))

 time y_ex1 y_ex2 y_ex3 y_ex4 y_ex5 y_ex1.score y_ex1.wave y_ex2.score y_ex2.wave
1     0     1     1     1     1     1         1.0          0         1.0          0
2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA     1         1.5          0         1.5          0
3     2     0     0     0     0     0         0.0          1         0.0          1
4     3     1     0     1     0     0         1.0          1         0.0          2
5     4    NA    NA    NA    NA     1         2.0          1         0.5          2
6     5    NA    NA    NA    NA     1         3.0          1         1.0          2
7     6    NA    NA    NA    NA     1         4.0          1         1.5          2
8     7     1     1     0     0     0         5.0          1         2.5          2
9     8     0     0     0     0     0         0.0          2         0.0          3
10    9     0     0     0     0     0         0.0          3         0.0          4
```